# Drone.io failed to received webhook from GitHub, but It's work if I send webhook payload manually

Tags: drone.io

I've using Drone as CI/CD for a year. But today my drone server just suddenly fails to received webhook from GitHub.

So I've go to GitHub's webhook section in the repository. And I see this

[image: GitHub failed to send webhook]

But the weird part is if I'm using the same payload as GitHub try to send to my drone server. It's actually work. And the build is succeed as usual.

Someone has any idea about this problem? Because it's just suddenly happen (no configuration change for a past month).

Comment: have you checked your drone server logs? If there is an error processing a webhook, drone will always write to the server logs (docker logs <server name>). If you don't see anything in the logs it would indicate the webhook is not even reaching the server, which might mean you have an issue upstream from the drone server. Please post server logs and can advise further.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my issue. Just change content type in GitHub webhook to `application/json` and it back to work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling and then re-enabling the repo in Drone is what fixed it for me.

[image: disable button on Drone repo settings]

See [discussion here](https://discourse.drone.io/t/error-cannot-find-yaml/9105) and [here](https://discourse.drone.io/t/we-couldn-t-deliver-this-payload-timed-out/10131)